# Bearer Tokenの入れ方について

Tags: python, twitter, webapi

Twitter APIのv2 full archive searchを使ってツイートを取得したいのですが、以下のようなエラーを得ました。
'OAuth 2.0 Bearer Token authentification'をしろということなので、Bearer tokenをapi.request()の中に入れたいのですが、他のコードなどを参考にしても上手くいきません。どなたかやり方が分かれば教えてください、よろしくお願いします。

エラーを得たコードは以下です。

```
from TwitterAPI import TwitterAPI, TwitterPager
import csv


SEARCH_TERM = '#metoomen lang:en'
PRODUCT = 'fullarchive'
LABEL = 'prod'


api = TwitterAPI(consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token_key, access_token_secret, api_version='2')

r = api.request('tweets/search/all', {'query':SEARCH_TERM, 
        'fromDate':'201710170000',
        'toDate':'201803312359',
        "maxResults":500
        })
    

csvFile = open('data.csv', 'w',encoding='UTF-8')
csvWriter = csv.writer(csvFile)

for item in r:
    csvWriter.writerow([item['created_at'],
                    item["id_str"],
                    item["source"],                    
                    item['user']['screen_name'],
                    item["user"]["location"],
                    item["geo"],
                    item["coordinates"], 
                    item['text'] if 'text' in item else item])

>>>
TwitterRequestError: ('{"title":"Unsupported Authentication","detail":"Authentication with OAuth 1.0a User Context is forbidden. Please, make the request with OAuth 2.0 Bearer Token authentication.","type":"https://api.twitter.com/2/problems/unsupported-authentication"}',) (403): {"title":"Unsupported Authentication","detail":"Authentication with OAuth 1.0a User Context is forbidden. Please, make the request with OAuth 2.0 Bearer Token authentication.","type":"https://api.twitter.com/2/problems/unsupported-authentication"}
```

api.request()に headers としてbearer tokenを入れれば良いと思うのですが、うまくいきませんでした。

```
headers = {"Authorization": "Bearer ***MYTOKEN***"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

お使いの[TwitterAPI](https://github.com/geduldig/TwitterAPI)は

```py
api = TwitterAPI(consumer_key,
                 consumer_secret,
                 auth_type='oAuth2')
```

のように指定することでOAuth2のApp Only Authenticationが利用できるようです。

ref: [TwitterAPI/authentication.rst](https://github.com/geduldig/TwitterAPI/blob/master/docs/authentication.rst)